# mysql python insert data given by user

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've been using this code to insert data given by user into mysql table using python, but the user given data doesn't show in MYSQL after I run the code:

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='CLOTHdb',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='')

sql_insert_Query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT_MASTER values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"


prod_code = int(input("Enter Product Code: "))
pname = input("Enter Product Name: ")
price = float(input("Enter Product Price: "))
pcolor = input("Enter Product Color: ")
pdesc = input("Enter Product Description: ")

param = (prod_code, pname, price, pcolor, pdesc)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_insert_Query,param)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total number of rows in table is: ", cursor.rowcount)

print("\nPrinting product info")

for row in records:
    print("prod_code = ", row[0], )
    print("pname = ", row[1])
    print("price  = ", row[2])
    print("pcolor  = ", row[3])
    print("pdesc = ", row[4], "\n")
```

Comment: Any most beginner python sql cursor example, could have solved this issue. e.g. 1) [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_access/python_mysql_insert_data.htm) 2) [doc-10.2.3 MySQLConnection.commit() Method

This method sends a COMMIT statement to the MySQL server, committing the current transaction. Since by default Connector/Python does not autocommit, it is important to call this method after every transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional storage engines. ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `commit()` method after executing the query for changes to the database.

```
cursor.execute(sql_insert_Query,param)
cursor.commit()
```